# How can I create a loop between two TTYs?

Tags: unix, tty

Every Hello has a response. Second TTY will send a hello to the sender TTY and vice versa:

```
echo 'echo hello > /dev/pts/1' > /dev/pts/0
```

The 1st receiver should send "hello" to the original sender, but it does not. What is wrong?

**[Clarification]** I have two shells running. /dev/pts/1 is the initial sender.

Comment: Do you have a shell running at /dev/pts/0?

Comment: Yes, I have two shells running. The initial sender is /dev/pts/1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send your echo command to `/dev/pts/0` you are literally just sending the output of that echo to the other TTY's **output** - you are **not** sending it to the other TTY's **input** buffers.  Therefore your nested `echo` command will simply be displayed on the other TTY, but not executed.

There is an `ioctl()` call `TIOCSTI` which can be used to fake input on another TTY, but only if you have "write" permission to that other TTY.

Many years ago I recall that some friends and I discovered holes on some versions of UNIX which didn't correctly enforce the security permissions on TIOCSTI.  If root had left a terminal logged in somewhere it was possible to make the root user's terminal type in commands on your behalf...